# Excel Date - 2 digit year appearing as 3 digits

Tags: excel

I enter the value 30/06/21 into a certain excel cell & it is returning/showing the date 30-06-212. If I delete the last 2 it will just re-enter the same value again

It is Date formatted & a header of a table. The other date header items are formatted the same but have the option to convert the dates to the 4 digit year while this cell does not

Comment: Sounds like your header is duplicated (if it is in a structured table)

Comment: ^ Column headers have to be unique in a table so Excel will automatically add the `2` since you already have used that header.